# I have downloaded eclipse and pydev, but I am unsure how to get install django

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I am attempting to learn how to create a website using python. I have been going off the advice of various websites including stackoverflow. Currently I can run code in eclipse using pydev, but I need to install django. I have no idea how to do this and I don't know who to ask or where to begin. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should have `pip` installed with your python installation.  The best choice for getting started will probably just be to run `pip install Django` from your command line, as recommended by [the official site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/install/#installing-official-release).  If you are new to python and don't have a working python install, you may want to consider installing python via [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

- Install virtual environment

`$pip install virtualenv`

- Create a new virtualenvironment

`$ virtualenv django-venv`

- Activate virtual environment & use

`$ source django-venv/bin/activate`

- And install django as expected

`(django-venv)$ pip install django==1.11.13`
(Replace with django version as needed)

Comment: Whenever I try and use "pip install..." it gives "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with a carrot pointing at install. I feel like this a problem with how I installed my python interpreter, but I am unsure how to fix it.

Comment: To ensure i can help accordingly, can you post the following: Are you using mac, windows, linux ? what is your python version ? you can find out using $python --version